# How to create a null pointer in a struct?

Tags: struct, rust

How do I create null pointer properties in struct like in C++? I do not quite understand how to make a pointer to an empty space in the memory.

**C++**

```cpp
struct test{
    string data;
    assocc *el;
}
srtuct assocc {
  T *data;
}
```

**Rust**

```
struct test {
     data: String,
     ponts: *const Option<assocc<T>>,
}

struct assocc<T> {
    data: T,
}

impl test {
   fn new(data: String) -> test {
      test {
          data: data,
          ponts: None,/*This don't work*/
      }
   }
}

impl<T> assocc<T> {
  fn new(data: T) -> assocc {
      assocc { 
          data: data,
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`std::ptr::null`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.null.html):

```
struct Test<T> {
     data: String,
     ponts: *const Option<Assocc<T>>,
}

struct Assocc<T> {
    data: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T> {
   fn new(data: String) -> Test<T> {
      Test {
          data: data,
          ponts: std::ptr::null(),
      }
   }
}

impl<T> Assocc<T> {
  fn new(data: T) -> Assocc<T> {
      Assocc {
          data: data,
      }
  }
}
```

But are you sure you want to use raw pointers in Rust? In Rust, we mostly use [references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/references-and-borrowing.html).

A more idiomatic way to do this in Rust is the following:

```
struct Test<'a, T: 'a> {
     data: String,
     ponts: Option<&'a Assocc<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Test<'a, T> {
   fn new(data: String) -> Test<'a, T> {
      Test {
          data: data,
          ponts: None,
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

There are a few issues with your code. To start out, Rust type names are generally CamelCased, so let's start with that:

```
struct Test {
     data: String,
     ponts: *const Option<Assocc<T>>,
}

struct Assocc<T> {
    data: T,
}
```

Next, because `Test` is enclosing something with a generic type `T`, it itself needs to be generic:

```
struct Test<T> {
     data: String,
     ponts: *const Option<Assocc<T>>,
}

struct Assocc<T> {
    data: T,
}
```

Unless you're doing FFI where you absolutely need to store a raw pointer, it's probably better to just have your `Test` struct own the `Assoc`:

```
struct Test<T> {
     data: String,
     ponts: Option<Assocc<T>>,
}

struct Assocc<T> {
    data: T,
}
```

And some of the types in the `impl` blocks need to be changed around to add some generics:

```
impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn new(data: String) -> Test<T> {
        Test {
            data: data,
            points: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Assocc<T> {
    fn new(data: T) -> Assocc<T> {
        Assocc { data: data }
    }
}
```

Finally, let's add a main function to ensure that we can actually use the structs as we're expecting:

```
struct Test<T> {
    data: String,
    ponts: Option<Assocc<T>>,
}

struct Assocc<T> {
    data: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn new(data: String) -> Test<T> {
        Test {
            data: data,
            ponts: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Assocc<T> {
    fn new(data: T) -> Assocc<T> {
        Assocc { data: data }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Test::new("Hello!".to_string());
    t.ponts = Some(Assocc::new(32));
}
```